# PHP sorting multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am currently sorting a multidimensional array using `usort` which lists my arrays in order of highest to lowest based on `value 1`, however with the highest sorted value, if there are multiple sub-arrays with the highest value I want to be able to then sort `value 2` based on the highest to lowest. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You do this right within the same `usort` callback. Something along these lines:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    if      ($a['foo'] < $b['foo']) return 1;
    else if ($a['foo'] > $b['foo']) return -1;
    else if ($a['bar'] < $b['bar']) return 1;
    else if ($a['bar'] > $b['bar']) return -1;
    else                            return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

you may be looking to do something like this:

```
$data = array(
               array('x', 'y', 'z'),
               array(3, 7, 2),
             );
array_multisort($data[0], SORT_DESC, SORT_STRING,
                $data[1], SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC);
var_dump($data);
```